# App re-open on same activity issue

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

I have 3 Activities, Activity1, Activity2 and Activity3. 
when app goes to background it always open from same activity. for example Activity1 is a Launcher Activity, than navigate to Activity2, now I pressed HOME Button and app goes to background, and whenever app re-opens it open Activity2. But on some devices (Samsung S5) i got problem, when App is on Activity2, Pressed Home button than re-open app it always open Activity1 which is launcher Activity. But I want when App re-open it will open same Activity where it was on last time.

Activity2 Code Below

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity2);
}

public void onActivity1(View view){
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
    mainIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    mainIntent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
    startActivity(mainIntent);
    Settings.this.finish();
}

public void onActivity3(View view) {
Intent infoIntent = new Intent(this, Activity3.class);
infoIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
infoIntent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
    startActivity(infoIntent);
    Settings.this.finish();
}
}
```

Below is manifest code

```
<activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity1"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity2"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity3"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: have you used finish() or something on your onpause method of your activity??

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: On which Activity? "Illegal Argument

Comment: You might try removing `android:stateNotNeeded="true"` from the manifest to see if this changes the behaviour. It is possible that the Samsung device is behaving strangely due to that. Otherwise, you should look at the activity stack using `adb shell dumpsys activity activities` after you press the HOME button to see if the state of your task is correct. Also look in the logcat to see if you see any relevant errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not possible since background activity can be killed by the system at any arbitrary time due to memory issue or some other reason. If your activity is killed by the OS, you can't get it back to the previous status (in here Activity2). Actually this is not device issue, it may depends on the device specifications, specially like memory.

Comment: This answer is untrue. If Android kills your process due to resource issues, it remembers exactly the state of the task and knows which Activity was on top. When the user returns to the application, Android will recreate the process and will then recreate the Activity that was on the top of the stack (in this case, Activity2). Only in cases where the user left the application in the background for a long time (usually 30 minutes or longer, this is device-specific) will Android discard the saved state and restart the application from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Try using android:launchmode="singleTask" for your MAIN activity :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in case you haven't read.

Answer (score -1):

Samsung seems to destroy your activity. But in generell use the Activity Lifecycle to understand when an activity is destroyed.

[image: http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/Android_Logcat-Activity-Starts.jpg]

Comment: I know about the Activity Lifecycle.